# WPF - Attach Binding Debugging when Binding is not in a string

Tags: wpf, binding, data-binding

Debugging a binding when it is like this

```
IsChecked="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, 
           AncestorType={x:Type ListBoxItem}}, Mode=TwoWay, Path=IsSelected}"
```

is easy.  You add the following:

```
xmlns:diagnostics="clr-namespace:System.Diagnostics;assembly=WindowsBase"


IsChecked="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, 
           AncestorType={x:Type ListBoxItem}}, Mode=TwoWay, 
           Path=IsSelected,diagnostics:PresentationTraceSources.TraceLevel=High}"
```

But how do you attach the "debugger" when your binding looks like this:

```
<DataTemplate.Triggers>
    <DataTrigger Value="True">
        <DataTrigger.Binding>
            <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource DisableWorkItemConverter}">
                <Binding ElementName="MainForm" Path="PickedWorkItemID"/>
                <Binding Path="WorkItemForColumn.Id"/>
            </MultiBinding>
        </DataTrigger.Binding>
        <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False"/>
        <Setter Property="loc:Main.IsCurrentItemEnabledChanged" Value="True"/>
    </DataTrigger>
</DataTemplate.Triggers>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sorry, I couldn't test it, but does this work?

```
  <DataTemplate.Triggers>
    <DataTrigger Value="True">
        <DataTrigger.Binding>
            <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource DisableWorkItemConverter}" 
                          diagnostics:PresentationTraceSources.TraceLevel="High">
                <Binding ElementName="MainForm" Path="PickedWorkItemID"/>
                <Binding Path="WorkItemForColumn.Id"/>
            </MultiBinding>
        </DataTrigger.Binding>
        <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False"/>        
    </DataTrigger>
```

Hope it does :).